# Does this theorem have a name, and where can I find a proof? "Every finite, weakly connected digraph contains at least one source or cycle."

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, directed-graphs

I am looking for a proof of a particular theorem. The theorem would state:

> Every finite, weakly connected digraph contains at least one source or cycle.

Since every finite graph is either cyclic or acyclic, an alternative statement would be:

> Every finite, weakly connected, acyclic digraph has a source.

with the previous theorem as a corollary.

**Note:** Assuming that the above is correct, then for any natural number $n$, an effective procedure exists to show that every weakly connected, acyclic digraph with fewer than $n$ vertices has a source - namely, "pick a point and backtrack". While this makes the theorem seem trivial, it is insufficient to prove that *every* finite, weakly connected, acyclic digraph has a source, hence the request for a proof.

---

I checked the library, all of my textbooks, and searched online, but I can't seem to find any reference to this theorem. The notion seems sufficiently obvious so as to be a fundamental result in graph theory, but no one I've spoken to has been able to put a name to it.

Is there a name for this theorem (or other, more significant theorem from which it can be easily derived), and where can I find a proof of it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a particular name for the theorem, but the idea of "pick a point and backtrack" is pretty much a proof - you can formalize it as follows, by proving the contrapositive:

> Let $G$ be a finite non-empty directed graph, none of which is a source. Then $G$ is cyclic.

Then to prove it, let $n$ be the number of vertices and let $x_0$ be an arbitrary vertex. Choose a sequence $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with the property that $x_i$ has an edge to $x_{i-1}$. This is possible since there are no sources. However, now we have a sequence $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ with $n+1$ elements, thus by the pigeonhole principle, some pair must be the same - that is $x_i=x_j$ for some $j\neq i$. Assume without loss of generality that $i>j$. Then $$x_i\rightarrow x_{i-1} \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow x_{j+1} \rightarrow x_j$$
is a cycle*.

(*If you insist upon a *simple* cycle, you can choose the a $(i,j)$ with $x_i=x_j$ and $i\neq j$ that minimizes $|i-j|$, since we know that the set of such pairs is non-empty)

Answer (score 0):

The digraph doesn't even need to be weakly connected, just non-empty.

Let $W$ be a directed walk in the digraph $D$ of maximal length.  (As $D$ is acyclic, the length of directed walks is bounded above by the number of nodes in $D$, so this is a valid construction.)  Consider $v$, the origin of $W$.  Since $D$ is acyclic, $D$ does not have an arc with $v$ as its tail whose head is another vertex in $W$.  Since $W$ is of maximal length, $D$ does not have an arc with $v$ as its tail whose head is vertex not in $W$.  Therefore, $v$ is a source.

Comment: Well, but nonemptiness does not suffice though. Also, a digraph can be not strongly connected but still be such that every vertex has indegree and outdegree at least one. Indeed take two vertex-disjoint directed cycles and put a directed edge from a vertex in one cycle to a vertex in another.

The property of being acyclic--connected or not--does suffice though.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, but still the origin of every maximal-length directed path in an acyclic directed graph (not even maximum, just something that is not a "subgraph" or a longer directed path) is a source.  Actually, now that I look at a definition, an isolated vertex is both a source and a sink, so really the digraph just needs a single vertex and no directed cycles to have a source.

Comment: Yes indeed. What you said in the 2nd paragraph of your answer is fine. The starting point of every *maximal* path [doesn't have to be *maximum*] is indeed a source. I do think the first paragraph of your answer may mislead some to say that every nonempty finite digraph has a source and of course that is not the case.